No reference found in Vs code Cucumber (Gherkin)

Here, the settings.json file
{ 
    "dotnet.defaultSolution": "selenium_tests/csharp.sln", 
    "dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "**/.sln", 
    "editor.quickSuggestion": { "comment": "on", "string": "on", "other": "on" }, 
    "window.level": 0, 
    "gherkin-autocomplete.featuresPath": "selenium_tests//Features", 
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [ "selenium_tests//.cs" ], 
    "cucumberautocomplete.synfeatures": "selenium_tests/**/Features"
}

I have Delete the settings.json file from .vscode/settings.json and added at global as shown in structure but still its not working getting reference not found.
Please help; still getting reference not found in feature file.

Can you [edit] your question to include more information about the error? The SpecFlow documentation indicates that there is no official support for SpecFlow in Visual Studio code. But it looks like there is a workaround.
